# Who added on the words לאלתר לחיים טובים ולשלום to the greeting לשנה טובה תכתב ותחתם?

Tags: sources-mekorot, blessing, provenance, rosh-hashanah-new-year

[Orach Chaim 582:9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=108) - The Rama brings in the name of the Tur that on Rosh Hashana one should bless his friend & family לשנה טובה תכתב. Be'er Hataiv says that one should say לשנה טובה תכתב ותחתם.

Now in many Siddurim & Machzorim it says to wish  לשנה טובה תכתב ותחתם לאלתר לחיים טובים ולשלום. What is the source for adding on the words לאלתר לחיים טובים ולשלום?

Comment: Surmising - The word "L'alter" means "immediately". I'm willing to bet this notion is related to the concept that *tzadikim* who have more mitzvoth than aveirot are immediately written in *Sefer Hachaim*, w/o having to wait until after Yom Kippur for the "decision". Thus, the wish conveys the idea that G-d considers you a tzadik who has more mitzvoth, and will inscribe you immediately. Can you provide a link or cite which Machzor has this?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10339

Comment: OOps. I misread the first word. I thought you asked "Why", not "Who".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Luach Hahalachos Uminhagim - 5771 page 30 - note 13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46120&st=&pgnum=30&hilite=) says this is based on the Chayai Adam 139:5 & Elef Hamagain 40

[Chayai Adam 139:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49395&st=&pgnum=339) says that one should say תכתב ותחתם לאלתר לחיים טובים

Elef Hamagain 40 says one should add Ulishilom